# DragDrop in WPF: Under which conditions the drop-event is raised?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I would like to know, if I can always rely on the assumption, that the event takes in account the effects which are set during the DragOver event in the Effects of the DragEventArgs.

In other words: If I implement logic in the DragOver event to determine if the drop is allowed and set the Effects to None if this is not the case, can I expect the drop event to not be raised?

Reason: I'm refactoring a project where there's logic in the DragOver-Eventhandler and some of it repeated in the Drop-Eventhandler and I'd like to move everything to the DragOver-Eventhandler. Are there any reasons against this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check `if(e.Effect != DragDropEffects.None)` (or similar..) in your drop event, than I don't think it will be a problem.
Another option is to use a boolean to check if a drop is allowed.

Comment: Good point! So I can rely on the test results of the DragOver Handler and can keep all tests there. Sorry that I couldn't think so far myself today...